Manwha where the hero meets a powerful girl as a child and goes off with a vow to get stronger and meet her again
There is a manhwa where the MC met a very powerful girl (may be a demon) as a child and he treated her very well. I believe he made a vow to get stronger to protect her and they split up for years. He goes on a mission to get stronger and finds a suit that makes him stronger but his body isn't strong enough to use it yet so he goes to some mountain and trains for years where he meets other masters. 1 is a female, one is a sword master and i cant remember the 3rd. Time goes on and the female leaves. He continues training and wants a stronger training so he trains in his mind for like 5000 years but it was only idk like a day. He meets back up with the swordmaster and unable to get stronger he voluntarily becomes a vampire. Last episode I remember he beat the swordmaster and he meets up with a doppelgänger of the girl who is now older.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it full-colour or black-and-white?

Is this Returning With Absolutely Nothing, a.k.a Possess nothing,
The plot match perfectly. However the details you remember may be in incorrect order. Please bear with me that I haven't read the manhwa due to its graphic but only the novel version so some details may mismatch
I will leave some details here, avoid spoiled as much as possible:

MC reincarnate and he struggle to live in city
MC meet the girl you mentionned and they had a vow with each other ( The one you remember)
Girl leave and MC stay a while in city due to some event needed
MC training in mountain and meet 3 master(the one you remember)
3 major event happen between here
MC face with the vampire swordmaster (the one you remember)
MC regret and decide to train more so MC go meet X and train his mind for thousand year (the one you remember)
MC enter the dungeon and meet the girl. Their distance is a wall which they can break but choose not to because the time isn't there yet. (the last thing you remember)

